# where/how to report that a question can't be viewed from the main page?

Tags: support

the question "XeTeX \left and \right problem" (question #30854) won't link from the main page.  (i managed to reach it by linking to the OP and then to the question, which did work.)  i think there may be unicode symbols in the title (they are certainly present in the text), and that may be part of the problem.

where and/or how should something like this be reported?  i considered flagging the question and writing a comment in the hope that a moderator would see it, but the question itself is a reasonable one, and i didn't want to give the impression that something was wrong with the content.

i don't think this this venue is really the correct place to report it either, but after looking through more than 300 meta questions found by a search on "view question" and finding nothing relevant, i took the easy way out.  (maybe i'm just not very good at thinking up suitable search terms.)

Comment: Do you mean yo can see it but the link doesn't work for you? Which link do you get? Or do you don't even see it?

Comment: i can see the question, but the link doesn't work. the page i'm looking at isn't the same one as in your answer, but the page that is displayed at [tex.stackexchange.com/questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions).  just checked again; the one on the main page (the one you show) does work; the one on the "questions" page still does not.  a puzzlement.

Comment: I checked the main page, you mean the question page, ok. However that one works for me as well. Could you please copy the link and show it here, using code backticks? Perhaps refresh the "broken" page in your browser.

Comment: here's the link to the question page after launching a new copy of the browser: `http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions`.  the link still doesn't work from there; all that shows is the cursor, not the little pointy finger.  i'm using firefox 7.0.1 (reported as up to date) on windows xp.  okay; i've just tried it on another box using windows 7, and it *does* work.  i guess it's my workstation.  sorry for the smoke, and thanks.  nonetheless, that still leaves the question, where's the best place to report such a question if it happens again?

Comment: If it seems to be site specific, it's good to post here on meta, as you did, with the {bug} tag. I'm sure that tag will be watched. If it's concerning SE in general, meta.SO would be better.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz, there is absolutely no need to send your users elsewhere.  The SE team monitors all metas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see it currently on the main page and the link works:

[image: screenshot excerpt]

Btw. I use Firefox on Ubuntu Linux. It could be a browser issue on your system.

Comment: apparently a local system problem (although reproducible).  tried another system and didn't have the problem.